# Frequency of receiving logs to QRadar

Tags: logging, qradar

hello i added a application source of logs , 
i receive a lot of logs since i added it, but the frequency in receiving log every day is very slow , i receive between 1 - 10 line of code every day, i add this source of log with log file and i made universal DSM ,
 i created a SFTP account, when i check my account i can receive until 65 000 line of log. i don't know where is the problem 
NB : my configuration is :
- Log source type : Universal DSM
- Protocol Configuration : Log File
-the file pattern i did (name of file).*.csv  ( because log's extension is .CSV)
- Processor : None
- Event Generator : LINEBYLINE
- File encoding : UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to increase "EPS Throttle" value ? This is the value of number of events for each connection.
Maybe you can get more logs with increasing this.

Regards

Comment: i did it but the same problem thank's for u're replay , i explain in other way: 1- when i do In File pattern Test.*.log , i receive a lot of log ( old one and newest one) but it stopped it doesn't import log in real time, 2- when i do in file pattern Test_16-05-2017.csv , i receive today's log in real time. It's not practicable to change every day the file pattern . How can i receive log in real time??